# How to get the 2nd id in a URL in JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

I have this url:
http://localhost:8080/owners/2/pets/2/edit

It follows this pattern:
http://localhost:8080/owners/${ownerId}/pets/${petId}/edit

I'd like to extract the 2nd id `petId` in JMeter. I've already extracted the 1st id `ownerId` by doing this:
[image]

I tried this:

[image]

then

[image]

but it didn't work, got this error:

java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 38: http://localhost:8080/owners/25/pets/${petId}/edit%20 at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2974)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression seems to be correct:

[image]

however the JMeter Variable isn't getting substituted with the extracted value which means that the Regular Expression Extractor fails to find the match. Double check which JMeter Variables are defined and what values do they have using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter), it might be the case you have a non-printable character like whitespace somewhere in the JMeter Variable name (like you do it after `edit`)

If this is not the case - make sure to choose correct "Field to check" and [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) for the Regular Expression Extractor.